# moyasar Saudi payment Gateway (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment, gateway

hope you are doing good. I want to integrate moyasar payment gateway in PHP/Codeigniter and I'm facing the same issue again and again (500 Internal Error. We're sorry. Unexpected service error occurred).
Is there any one who can figure out this error. Help will be appreciated.
Error with image is here!
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4eoL.png)
Simple Code is given below..

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://api.moyasar.com/v1/payments.html" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="source[name]" />
    <input type="text" name="source[number]" />
    <input type="text" name="source[month]" />
    <input type="text" name="source[year]" />
    <input type="text" name="source[cvc]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="callback_url" value="http://localhost/test/madas.php" />
    <input type="hidden" name="publishable_api_key" value="my_publish_api_key" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10000" />
    <input type="hidden" name="source[type]" value="mada" />
    <button type="submit" id="">Purchase</button>
</form>
```

Comment: If that error is on your server check the server log. If it is on the payments site contact their support. A 500 is a general error and you have to check the logs to find out what really happened.

Answer (score 0):

`source[type]` value should be `creditcard` and it accepts Mada, Visa, and MasterCard.